# Mysql Select Query Success on Mysql Client But Failed through PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i have a query which run fine through heidisql but if through PHP, it fails without any error report.

Here is the code

**PHP**

```
    $sql = "SELECT `pob`.`id` , `pob`.`po_qty` , ifnull(`mrb`.`rcv_qty`,0) as `rcv_qty` , ( `pob`.`po_qty` - ifnull( sum( `mrb`.`rcv_qty` ), 0 )) AS balance FROM `mpo_body` AS `pob` LEFT JOIN `mrcv_body` AS `mrb` ON `pob`.`id` = `mrb`.`po_id` WHERE `pob`.`id`='$id' GROUP BY `pob`.`id`";

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows>0){
        $row = $result -> fetch_assoc();
        if($row['balance']>0){
            $sql = "UPDATE `mpo_body` SET close='Y' WHERE `id`='$id'";
            echo $mysqli->query($sql);
        }else{
            echo "failed here";
        }
    }else{
        echo "failed at here";
    }
```

What causing the problem here?

UPDATE

this is the structure of data in mpo_body

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mpo_body`;

CREATE TABLE `mpo_body` (   `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `po_no` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',   `item_no` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',   `matcode` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',   `po_qty` decimal(16,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',   `unit_price` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',   `etd_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0001-01-01',   `po_bal` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `ref_no` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',   `dept_no` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',   `uom` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',   `factor` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',   `rev_no` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',   `cancel` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',   `del_note` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',   `closed` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',   `upt_time` time NOT NULL,   `prid` int(11) NOT NULL,   `remark` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),   KEY `matcode` (`matcode`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

LOCK TABLES `mpo_body` WRITE; /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `mpo_body` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `mpo_body` (`id`, `po_no`, `item_no`, `matcode`, `po_qty`, `unit_price`, `etd_date`, `po_bal`, `ref_no`, `dept_no`, `uom`, `factor`, `rev_no`, `cancel`, `del_note`, `closed`, `upt_time`, `prid`, `remark`) VALUES     (1,'P05-000001','002','30001352',1.00,1.00,'2016-05-28',1,'','PURCHASING','PCS',1,'','N','','N','00:00:00',21,''),  (2,'P05-000001','001','30001352',1.00,1.00,'2016-05-28',1,'','PPMC','PCS',1,'','N','','N','00:00:00',4,'');

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `mpo_body` ENABLE KEYS */; UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: And what's the error? `echo mysqli_error()`

Comment: May be `echo` cause problem at `echo $mysqli->query($sql);`

Comment: add ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); or error_reporting(E_ALL); at top of the php file and see whats the error thrown

Comment: the error `Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string` generated from `echo $mysqli->query($sql);`

Comment: remove echo from it!!

Comment: if `echo` removed was from `mysqli->query($sql)` the console show nothing.

Comment: Try var_dump(mysqli->query($sql) might be connection issue.

Comment: @Ali this what i got i `var_dump` `object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(4)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(1)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}`

Comment: So connection is fine and you are also fetch data as well. Now check var_dump for $row that it has array index of balance or not.

Comment: `array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["po_qty"]=>
  string(4) "1.00"
  ["rcv_qty"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["balance"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}` seems no problem with the balance field

Comment: try to change       $sql = "UPDATE `mpo_body` SET close='Y' WHERE `id`='".$id."'";

Comment: @theinarasu still the same as above

Comment: found the issue, the field name is closed instead of close, sorry  guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, i found out the problem, i missed the field name, it should be `closed` instead of `close`, updated the wrong field name in `mpo_body` table.

Answer (score 0):

You must use while as bellow:

```
$sql = "SELECT `pob`.`id` , `pob`.`po_qty` , ifnull(`mrb`.`rcv_qty`,0) as `rcv_qty` , ( `pob`.`po_qty` - ifnull( sum( `mrb`.`rcv_qty` ), 0 )) AS balance FROM `mpo_body` AS `pob` LEFT JOIN `mrcv_body` AS `mrb` ON `pob`.`id` = `mrb`.`po_id` WHERE `pob`.`id`='$id' GROUP BY `pob`.`id`";

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows>0){

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             if($row['balance']>0){
                $sql = "UPDATE `mpo_body` SET close='Y' WHERE `id`='$id'";
                echo $mysqli->query($sql);
            }else{
                echo "failed here";
            }
        }

    }else{
        echo "failed at here";
    }
```

Comment: do i have to use `while` if only 1 record will be returned by the query?

Comment: Yes, It's not required

Comment: still the same, nothing happened

Comment: Could you dump detail mpo_body table and send to me? I will try to run it in my localhost

Comment: how to sent it to you?

Comment: you can paste the sql content on here

Comment: ok, i saw problem. Your data base define  `closed` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N' but in  $sql = "UPDATE `mpo_body` SET close='Y' WHERE `id`='$id'"; you use 'close'. Please update to 'closed'

Answer (score 0):

Did you debug what is the response of $row? print $row variable there is no need of loop the behavior of CI is it will provide index wise array. so if you want to access value your condition should be if($row['balance'][0] > 0) like this.

Comment: `var_dump($row)` result is `array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["po_qty"]=> string(4) "1.00" ["rcv_qty"]=> string(1) "0" ["balance"]=> string(1) "1" }`